# Ceaser Cipher Using OOP Logic

Tags: python

Below is my code for a class based Ceaser's cipher, this is for MIT 6.001 Ps4b.py

Question:

In the test cases at the end of the code file (test case#02), the expected output is *(24, 'hello')*.

While the actual output of the program is *(2, 'hello')*

And this makes sense because lines 330-332 :

```
plaintext = PlaintextMessage('hello', 2)
print('Expected Output: jgnnq')
print('Actual Output:', plaintext.get_message_text_encrypted())
```

creates an instance of PlaintextMessage with the shift value set to 2.
where 'jgnnq' is the encryption of 'hello'.

And lines 335-337:

```
ciphertext = CiphertextMessage('jgnnq')
print('Expected Output:', (24, 'hello'))
print('Actual Output:', ciphertext.decrypt_message())
```

here:
string = 'jgnnq'
decrypted string = 'hello'
best factor actual is 2, but expected is 24
should print a tuple containing the factor used to (de)crypt the string  and the decrypted string (which is 'hello').

So my question is why is the expected 'best factor' for test case#02 is 24 while the factor used to (de)crypt the string is 2.

The test cases are provided by MIT OCW and were not modified on my part.

Code:

```
def load_words(file_name):
    '''
    file_name (string): the name of the file containing 
    the list of words to load    

    Returns: a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    '''
    # print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(file_name, 'r')
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = []
    for line in inFile:
        wordlist.extend([word.lower() for word in line.split(' ')])
    # print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
    return wordlist



def is_word(word_list, word):
    '''
    Determines if word is a valid word, ignoring
    capitalization and punctuation

    word_list (list): list of words in the dictionary.
    word (string): a possible word.

    Returns: True if word is in word_list, False otherwise

    Example:
    >>> is_word(word_list, 'bat') returns
    True
    >>> is_word(word_list, 'asdf') returns
    False
    '''
    word = word.lower()

    word = word.strip(" !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")
    return word in word_list

def get_story_string():
    """
    Returns: a story in encrypted text.
    """
    f = open("story.txt", "r")
    story = str(f.read())
    f.close()
    return story

WORDLIST_FILENAME = 'words.txt'
words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME) 


class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        '''
        Initializes a Message object

        text (string): the message's text

        a Message object has two attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
        '''

        self.message_text = text
        self.valid_words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME)
        #self.valid_words = [word for word in text.split() if is_word(words, word)]



    def get_message_text(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.message_text outside of the class

        Returns: self.message_text
        '''
        return self.message_text


    def get_valid_words(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access a copy of self.valid_words outside of the class.
        This helps you avoid accidentally mutating class attributes.

        Returns: a COPY of self.valid_words
        '''
        return self.valid_words.copy()


    def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
        '''
        Creates a dictionary that can be used to apply a cipher to a letter.
        The dictionary maps every uppercase and lowercase letter to a
        character shifted down the alphabet by the input shift. The dictionary
        should have 52 keys of all the uppercase letters and all the lowercase
        letters only.        

        shift (integer): the amount by which to shift every letter of the 
        alphabet. 0 <= shift < 26

        Returns: a dictionary mapping a letter (string) to 
                 another letter (string). 
        '''

        lowercase_letters = ascii_lowercase
        uppercase_letters = ascii_uppercase

        # alphabet = lowercase_letters + uppercase_letters

        # alphabet_shifted = alphabet[-shift:] + alphabet[:-shift]

        lowercase_shifted = lowercase_letters[shift:] + lowercase_letters[:shift]

        uppercase_shifted = uppercase_letters[-shift:] + uppercase_letters[:-shift]

        # shift_dict = {letter: shift for letter, shift in zip(alphabet, alphabet_shifted)}

        shift_dict_lowercase = {letter: shift for letter, shift in zip(lowercase_letters, lowercase_shifted)}

        shift_dict_uppercase = {letter: shift for letter, shift in zip(uppercase_letters, uppercase_shifted)}


        return [shift_dict_lowercase, shift_dict_uppercase]



    def apply_shift(self, shift):
        '''
        Applies the Caesar Cipher to self.message_text with the input shift.
        Creates a new string that is self.message_text shifted down the
        alphabet by some number of characters determined by the input shift        

        shift (integer): the shift with which to encrypt the message.
        0 <= shift < 26

        Returns: the message text (string) in which every character is shifted
             down the alphabet by the input shift
        '''
        shift_dict_lowercase, shift_dict_uppercase = self.build_shift_dict(shift)

        plain_msg = self.message_text

        encrypted_msg = []


        for char in plain_msg:
            if char in ascii_lowercase:
                encrypted_msg.append(shift_dict_lowercase[char])
            elif char in ascii_uppercase:
                encrypted_msg.append(shift_dict_uppercase[char])
            else:
                encrypted_msg.append(char)


        # encrypted_msg = [shift_dict_lowercase.get(char, char) for char in plain_msg]

        return ''.join(encrypted_msg)



class PlaintextMessage(Message):
    def __init__(self, text, shift):
        '''
        Initializes a PlaintextMessage object        

        text (string): the message's text
        shift (integer): the shift associated with this message

        A PlaintextMessage object inherits from Message and has five attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
            self.shift (integer, determined by input shift)
            self.encryption_dict (dictionary, built using shift)
            self.message_text_encrypted (string, created using shift)

        '''
        Message.__init__(self, text)
        self.shift = shift
        self.encryption_dict = self.build_shift_dict(shift)
        self.message_text_encrypted = self.apply_shift(shift)



    def get_shift(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.shift outside of the class

        Returns: self.shift
        '''
        return self.shift

    def get_encryption_dict(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access a copy self.encryption_dict outside of the class

        Returns: a COPY of self.encryption_dict
        '''
        return self.encryption_dict.copy()


    def get_message_text_encrypted(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.message_text_encrypted outside of the class

        Returns: self.message_text_encrypted
        '''
        return self.message_text_encrypted


    def change_shift(self, shift):
        '''
        Changes self.shift of the PlaintextMessage and updates other 
        attributes determined by shift.        

        shift (integer): the new shift that should be associated with this message.
        0 <= shift < 26

        Returns: nothing
        '''
        self.__init__(self.message_text, shift)

class CiphertextMessage(Message):
    def __init__(self, text):
        '''
        Initializes a CiphertextMessage object

        text (string): the message's text

        a CiphertextMessage object has two attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
        '''
        Message.__init__(self, text)



        # need to optimize this:


    def decrypt_message(self):
        '''
        Decrypt self.message_text by trying every possible shift value
        and find the "best" one. We will define "best" as the shift that
        creates the maximum number of real words when we use apply_shift(shift)
        on the message text. If s is the original shift value used to encrypt
        the message, then we would expect 26 - s to be the best shift value 
        for decrypting it.

        Note: if multiple shifts are equally good such that they all create 
        the maximum number of valid words, you may choose any of those shifts 
        (and their corresponding decrypted messages) to return

        Returns: a tuple of the best shift value used to decrypt the message
        and the decrypted message text using that shift value
        '''
        # using a dictonary to get the max number of valid words in a string
        # have to figure out how to see if a word is valid after applying the 
        # shift to it.
        results = {}
        words_found = {n: [] for n in range(26)}
        for n in range(26):
            for word in self.message_text.split():
                m = Message(word)
                word = m.apply_shift(-n)
                # print(word)
                if is_word(words, word):
                    results[n] = results.get(n, 0) + 1
                    words_found[n].append(word)
        # print(results)
        # print(words_found)
        # print(max(results))

        best_factor = max(results)


        return best_factor, PlaintextMessage(self.message_text, -best_factor).get_message_text_encrypted()


        # num_words_per_factor = {n:len(words_found[n]) for n in range(26)}
        # best_factor = 
        # print(best_factor)


# plain_text_msg = PlaintextMessage('Hello, Cat, Dog, Kate', 0)  

# print(plain_text_msg.get_message_text())

# encrypted_msg = plain_text_msg.apply_shift(3)   

# print(encrypted_msg)

# cipher_msg = CiphertextMessage(encrypted_msg)

# decrypted_msg = cipher_msg.decrypt_message()

# print(decrypted_msg)   


if __name__ == '__main__':

#    #Example test case (PlaintextMessage)
#    plaintext = PlaintextMessage('hello', 2)
#    print('Expected Output: jgnnq')
#    print('Actual Output:', plaintext.get_message_text_encrypted())
#
#    #Example test case (CiphertextMessage)
#    ciphertext = CiphertextMessage('jgnnq')
#    print('Expected Output:', (24, 'hello'))
#    print('Actual Output:', ciphertext.decrypt_message())

    #TODO: WRITE YOUR TEST CASES HERE

    #TODO: best shift value and unencrypted story 

    #Example test case (PlaintextMessage)
    plaintext = PlaintextMessage('hello', 2)
    print('Expected Output: jgnnq')
    print('Actual Output:', plaintext.get_message_text_encrypted())

    #Example test case (CiphertextMessage)
    ciphertext = CiphertextMessage('jgnnq')
    print('Expected Output:', (24, 'hello'))
    print('Actual Output:', ciphertext.decrypt_message())
```

Comment: Sounds like you are counting the shift in the wrong direction.  With a 26-character alphabet, a shift of 2 in one direction is the same thing as a shift of 24 in the other.

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decrypting with a certain factor you should shift in the opposite direction in respect to encrypt operation.

Note that 24 = -2 (mod 26).

The expected output apparently is looking for the shift value to apply with the encoding procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. 
Was able to adjust the line :

```
lowercase_shifted = lowercase_letters[shift:] + lowercase_letters[:shift]
```

to

```
lowercase_shifted = lowercase_letters[-shift:] + lowercase_letters[:-shift]
```

And changed decrypt_message function to be:

```
def decrypt_message(self):
        '''
        Decrypt self.message_text by trying every possible shift value
        and find the "best" one. We will define "best" as the shift that
        creates the maximum number of real words when we use apply_shift(shift)
        on the message text. If s is the original shift value used to encrypt
        the message, then we would expect 26 - s to be the best shift value 
        for decrypting it.

        Note: if multiple shifts are equally good such that they all create 
        the maximum number of valid words, you may choose any of those shifts 
        (and their corresponding decrypted messages) to return

        Returns: a tuple of the best shift value used to decrypt the message
        and the decrypted message text using that shift value
        '''
        # using a dictonary to get the max number of valid words in a string
        # have to figure out how to see if a word is valid after applying the 
        # shift to it.

        def get_key(val, my_dict): 
            for key, value in my_dict.items(): 
                if val == value: 
                    return key 

            return "key doesn't exist"

        results = {}
        # shift can range from 0 to 26
        words_found = {n: [] for n in range(27)}
        for n in range(26):
            for word in self.message_text.split():
                m = Message(word)
                word = m.apply_shift(-n)
                # print(word)
                if is_word(words, word):
                    results[n] = results.get(n, 0) + 1
                    words_found[n].append(word)

        best_factor = get_key(max(results.values()), results)


        # print(best_factor)

        return 26-best_factor, PlaintextMessage(self.message_text, -best_factor).get_message_text_encrypted()
```

and now the actual output matches the expected.